# How can i display an image to another client for 1 hour and give him the option to save the image

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I'm new on node.js, i'm trying to make a simple sharing picture app, and my problem is:
with the server i get an error on line 13 that says "require(...).listen is not a function"
and how can i implement that when i upload a picture as a client that other clients can see the picture for 1 hour and in that 1 hour they can save it and if they want the other clients can add a new picture instead of the one that has been added so other clients can save it and can see it.
My main goal is:
Frontend: Which allows the customer to take a photo and upload it at a specific time.
When the time comes, you need to show the image to anyone who opens your site.
Back End: That allows each of your customers to take a photo and save it until time runs out and shows all customers the photo.

my code:
server with an error on line 13 that I couldn't resolve

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
fs.readFile('./index.html', 'utf-8', function(error, content) {
res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
res.end(content);
});
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
    socket.on('user image',function (image){
       io.sockets.emit('addimage', {'src' :image});
    });
 });

app.get('/',function (req,res) {
    res.render('index');
})

server.listen(8080,function () {
    console.log('listen port 8080')
})
```

html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
      <meta charset=utf-8 />
      <title>Upload your Image</title>
      <style>
       article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
       menu, nav, section { display: block; }
      </style>
   </head>
    <body>
        <div><input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" /></div></b>
        <div><img id="img" src="" /></div> 
        <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script> 

         var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

         socket.on('addimage',function(msg){
            //reading src property from msg as per changes
            $('#img')
                .attr('src', msg.src)
                .width(800)
                .height(400);
});

function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#img')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(800)
                .height(400);
             socket.emit('user image', e.target.result);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
  </script>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your JS,
Try using:

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
```

and on line 13:

```
var { Server } = require("socket.io");
var io = new Server(server);
```

and instead of:

```
io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
  socket.on('user image',function (image){
    io.sockets.emit('addimage', {'src' :image});
  });
});
```

try using:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('user image', function(image) {
    io.emit('addimage', {'src' :image});
  });
});
```

**Edit:** also, to serve the client your home page, try this in `app.get("/", function(req, res) {...})`

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

and in your internal JS in your HTML file:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:8080');

// if above does not work, try the below instead:
var socket = io();
```

I don't know if it will help you but hopefully it will. However you might need to change some of the code to work with the below suggestions.

The suggestions were based off the Socket.io documentation. Also you might want to see their example on building a chat application. Might help you with something:

**Reference**

1. Socket.io

   - [Documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/)
   - [Chat Application](https://socket.io/get-started/chat)

Comment: hey the server itself loads but it dosent show any html would love to get your help to fix it thanks so much sir

Comment: Hi, @dezlight, I've edited. If you use ```res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');``` in your ```app.get("/", ...)```, it should show the home page. Does it work for you?